# Mongoose findOne callback not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Mongoose findOne function call does nothing and I am in trouble again. Callback is not never returned...

schema.js file:

```
var schemaSizeGroup = new Schema({
     sizeGroupId        :   {type: Number, required: true, index: true, index: { unique: true }}
    ,sizeGroupName      :   {type: String, required: true, trim: true, index: { unique: true }}
    ,sizeGroupValues    :   {type: String, required: true, trim: true }
    ,active             :   {type: Boolean, default: true }
}, { collection: 'sizegroup' }).index({sizeGroupId : 1});


module.exports ={
    SizeGroup       : mongoose.connection.model('SizeGroup', schemaSizeGroup),
}
```

index.js file:

```
findDocumentById : function(sGroupId, callback){
        winston.info("  Trying to select!");
        model.SizeGroup.findOne( {sizeGroupId : sGroupId} ,function(err, sGroup) {

            winston.info("  Select done:");
            winston.info(JSON.stringify(sGroup,null,2));

            if(!err) {
                if(!sGroup) {
                    callback(new Error("  No SizeObject Found for Id:" + sizeGroupId));
                } else { callback(null, sGroup); }
             }
             else {
                callback(err);
             }
        });
    }
}
```

selectin data using mongo client returns correct data nicely:

```
db.sizegroup.find({sizeGroupId : 6});
```

When using mongoose.set('debug', true) output looks like:

```
Mongoose: sizegroup.findOne({ sizeGroupId: 6 }) { fields: undefined }
```

I have active mongoose connection, because all the previous insert statements have been successful.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The findOne is working when it is done in different program after this one is finished. All the inserts in the program are done using async.series and also mongoose.set('debug', true) output is proving that right. Any comments why I cant access the data inside same program....

Answer (score 0):

It was a callback problem in program flow. Clear case of pure stupidity....